# Understanding Forms Events - Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

lets say i have form like follow in my controller

```
$data = [];
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
            ->add('username', 'text', [ 'mapped' => FALSE, 'required' => FALSE ])
            ->add('show_email', 'checkbox', [ 'mapped' => FALSE, 'required' => FALSE ])
            ->add('submit', 'submit')
            ->addEventListener(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function($event){
                $user = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm();

                if (true == $user['show_email']) {
                    $form->add('email', 'email', [
                        'required' => FALSE,
                         'data' => 'test@gmail.com'
                    ]); 
                }

                $form->setData($user);
            })
            ->getForm()
            ;
    $form->handleRequest($request);
```

and I am listening to the `PRE_SUBMIT` event to add `email` field when a user checks the `show_email`.During the  `PRE_SUBMIT`, the `email` field added successfully but when I am trying assign data in that field it is not shown in the form view. In the example, i use `'data' => 'test@gmail.com'` to add value to that `email field`, but that value is not populating in the email field. so what mistake I made here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding `email` field value to the `event data`, like `$data['email'] = "test@gmail.com"`, then `reassign` the event data `$event->setData($data)` again.

```
 ->addEventListener(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function($event){

                $form = $event->getForm();
                $data = $event->getData();

                if(isset($data['showEmail']) && $data['showEmail'] == TRUE){
                    $form->add('email', 'email', [
                       'mapped' => FALSE ,
                    ]);
                    $data['email'] = "test@gmail.com";
                }
                else
                {
                    unset($data['email']);
                }

                $event->setData($data);
            })
```